# download azure diagnostic logs?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Does anyone know how to download the Azure diagnostic logs?  From the control panel, it shows me an ftp link for the logs, but when I click it it prompts me for a username/password.  Any username/password I try just results in a "530 User Cannot Login" error.

It looks like the same address that Vis Studio does it's publishing to, and that had a '$' before my username.  I tried that as well, but no-go.

Just curious how to get the logs when you start having errors pop up in the application, or is there something else I should be doing to prepare my app for going on Azure?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You would need to use FTP client application to access to files instead of using the Webpage as it is designed to use a client app to display the files.

I have configured FileZilla as below to access my Windows Azure websites to access Diagnostics Logs as well as use the same client application to upload/download site specific files:

[image]

In my blog [Windows Azure Website: Uploading/Downloading files over FTP and collecting Diagnostics logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx), I have described all the steps.

Comment: Thanks alot AvkashChauhan, that's exactly what I needed.  I tried using a client as well, but wasn't able to figure out the username/pw to use... your post set it all straight.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, but what determines the domain you used?  We are using an enterprise Azure account and I'm unsure of the domain.  I'm also trying to set it up over ftps and I'll post any additional instructions for that when I get that all sorted.

Comment: See below for the updated answer 3 years later, things had changed quite a bit unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

**As an update as of December 2015 (New Azure Portal) 
Apparently the FTP Username and Password is not set by your publish settings or anything else that I can find.**

The steps to first set up your FTP credentials are to go to your web app on the new portal. Click the settings icon at the top of the "blade". There's like 25-30 different links to settings there. The one we want is under Publishing and then Deployment Credentials.

I thought I had already set these up with my publish profile but those were not working. You should have the opportunity to enter your desired username and password now for FTP and git specifically.

Now go to the blade for Diagnostics (It was right above the publishing section) and you can copy the ftp url. I just copied the first one (ftp not ftps), went to FileZilla and used the ftp url, my new username and password, and port 21 and I was able to see all log files as expected.

This does NOT mess up or affect your publishing credentials in any way that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

On the new Azure Portal there's a new concept of [site extensions](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/20/azure-web-sites-extensions/) there you can find an extension called **Azure Website Log Browser** which makes it extremly easy for you to access your website's logs (viewing and downloading them).

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/).

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the process, for me it was:

1. Setup APP server properly (Deployment -> Deployment Credentials ... set username and password
2. Read correct username at Monitoring -> Diagnostic Logs ... there's a label with SERVERNAME\USERNAME (this whole is username!)
3. Use WinSCP for SFTP connection and configure it properly. Then I was able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but your image helped solve my problem.  I wasn't using the [sitename][username]  (I say sitename but perhaps I should call it hostname/domain)

I don't know if this will help you, and you may have already tried it, but the username I used was my Windows Live ID.  (I did *not* use the dollar $ign)

Oh and one other thing and I don't know if this matters or not as far as accessing the ftp site where logs are stored but make sure you have enabled them under Websites | [select your website] |  Configure  -  Then scroll down to Diagnostics and click "ON" for the logs you want turned on.

I added that last part because I don't know if your ftp.[sitename].azurewebsites.windows.net/LogFiles/  directory has been created and since this is where I am dropped off at (/LogFiles) after signing in, if it doesn't exist you might not be able to log on.. just an after thought.

Good luck!
John

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set up deployment credentials for the application.  This is needed by FTP.  (Example user name: MyFtpUserName)

Then, when browsing to that provided ftp link, remember to qualify the user id with the domain.  (Example qualified user name: MyWebSiteName\MyFtpUserName)