# Connecting to an Azure website via FTP using Azure login credentials

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

What login credentials do I use to connect to the FTP site that is listed on the dashboard of my Azure?

I tried using the same credentials I use to log into Azure, but this failed.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In the **[current Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)** the deployment credentials can be set by going to *App Services* → select the relevant app service item → in the *Deployment* section → *Deployment Center* → *FTP* → *Dashboard*. You can either chose to use the preprovided **App Credentials** or assign **User Credentials**.

In the [previous generation Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) the deployment credentials can be set up by going to *WEB APPS* → select relevant item → *DASHBOARD* → *Reset your deployment credentials*.

Make sure you're specifying **siteName\userName** as your login name. The site name portion is required!

The default directory for the web content is **\site\wwwroot** which can be set as the initial directory for many FTP clients.

Comment: For some reason, when I try to connect to the FTP Host Name using credentials I just setup using link "Setup your deployment credentials", server returns 530: user cannot log in.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11112983/468244)? are you using the full credentials including site and a proper ftp client?

Comment: Just figured the missing element before my actual username i.e site\ftp_user_name.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have a related issue. No matter how many times I reset the deployment credentials, when I access properties it alwas says there is no ftp/deployment user set. ANd no ftp access is allowed. Winscp says "can not resolve host". Which is even weirder since the same url propmts credential when used in a browser. any thoughts on this? I only need to acces wordpress ocnfig file to set some variables there

Comment: What do you mean by "when I access properties it alwas says there is no ftp/deployment user set"? Would it be a good idea to properly document your situation in a new question?

Comment: Where is "Reset your deployment credentials"?

Comment: I had to enter \site\wwwroot as my remote path before I could connect via FTP.

Comment: The entry **Deployment Credentials** has been moved to **App Deployment** in the (as of now) newest version of the portal. It's still part of the ribbon on the left hand side though.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the comment. I updated the answer to better reflect the current state of the portal.

Comment: @SimonOpelt, could you update your answer to also include the fact that you are required to connect to your root folder (\[sitename]\wwwroot\) for your credentials to work? I read that in one of the comments and it solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Murven, thank you for the input. I should always be `\site\wwwroot` for the default deployment directory independent of the site name. Furthermore most clients should be fine not specifying a directory and just landing in `\` as all accessible directories should be perfectly readable. I could not find any documentation that would explain why directly starting at that directory should be required.

Comment: Jan 2019 - New instructions for new UI: Go to App Services / select relevant item / in the DEPLOYMENT section / Deployment Center / Deployment Credentials / App credentials. The ftp username is the displayed username but without the `$` sign. Or go to User credentials to set your own username and password.

Comment: you have to use nameofyoursite NOT nameofyoursite\$nameofyoursite as username

Answer (score 105):

If you want use the default value you need to download the publish profile in your dashboard for your site:

[image]

**[UPDATE for the new Azure UI]**

[image]

It will be an XML file. Open it and find your credentials. Sample:

```
  <publishProfile
    profileName="nameofyoursite - FTP"
    publishMethod="FTP"
    publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-blu-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot"
    ftpPassiveMode="True"
    userName="nameofyoursite\$nameofyoursite"
    userPWD="sOmeCrYPTicL00kIngStr1nG"
    destinationAppUrl="http://nameofyoursite.azurewebsites.net"
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    hostingProviderForumLink=""
    controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com">
    <databases/>
  </publishProfile>
```

Where your credentials:

publishUrl="ftp://**waws-prod-blu-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net**/site/wwwroot"

userName="**nameofyoursite$nameofyoursite**"

userPWD="**sOmeCrYPTicL00kIngStr1nG**"

Source:  [Azure Web Sites FTP credentials](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/azure-web-sites-ftp-credentials)

---

---

**Connection from command line on OS X:**

Console client:

```
ftp ftp://nameofyoursite:sOmeCrYPTicL00kIngStr1nG@waws-prod-blu-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/
```

Mount from the console:

```
mkdir /Users/<YOUR_USER>/FTP_AZURE
mount_ftp nameofyoursite:sOmeCrYPTicL00kIngStr1nG@waws-prod-blu-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/ /Users/<YOUR_USER>/FTP_AZURE
cd /Users/<YOUR_USER>/FTP_AZURE
```

**Open for editing in Vim:**

```
vim ftp://nameofyoursite@waws-prod-blu-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.ne//site/wwwroot/
```

Note the user name here: **nameofyoursite**, ***not*** **nameofyoursite$nameofyoursite**

Comment: "Note user name here: nameofyoursite NOT nameofyoursite\$nameofyoursite". You saved my day! Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried everything, still getting timeout :(
By trying the last ftp cmd i got Name or service not known

Comment: @user358448, I would suggest check names for you server and settings. Should work.

Comment: Note that using the default FTP client on Windows, you have to give the open command without "ftp://" in the server URL.

Comment: plus one this maybe the most useful answer here.

Answer (score 15):

To be complete, you can FTP using **two different** credentials:

1. It is already mentioned by @0x8BADF00D. If you downloaded the 'publish profile', you can see the **automatically generated credentials for each site**.

   In short, if `x=your website name`, then `username=x\$x` and the password is a long system generated string

   [image]

   **Obviously, this is not meant for a human user...at least I cannot easily remember a 20+ character random string...**
2. There is a more user friendly way. You can set a username and password in Azure portal

   [image]

   However, **"deployment user name" is directly tied to a Microsoft account. [It is the same for all your web applications](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials#user-level-credentials-aka-deployment-credentials)**. In order to use it to ftp into different web applications, you need to add a prefix.

   Here, my username is "blabla", and my website name is "test" ==> **my FTP username is thus "test\blabla"** (mind the backslash on Windows) followed by the password I set on Azure portal (no modification required):

   [image]

Here are the references from Azure:

- *[Why there are two credentials for FTP](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials)*
- *[How to log in with the user friendly credential](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp)*

Answer (score 2):

In the Azure portal (end of 2018):

1. Go to your app
2. In the left pane, select **Deployment Center**
3. In the middle pane, select **FTP**
4. Click view dashboard, and there you have your ftps connection url, username and password.

*You must enable FTP/S on your web app to actually be able to connect! This is done under Application Settings -> FTP Access in the Azure portal*

Answer (score 2):

These two blades give all the required information to connect via FTP.

#### App Service > Settings > Properties

[image]

#### App Service > Deployment > Deployment Center > Deployment Credentials

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of ["blades"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blade#Noun) in this context? None of the 23 listed items seem to fit. Presumably not as in [blade server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_server)