# Can't ftp to azure webapp

Tags: php, azure, ftp, timeout, azure-web-app-service

I've created simple webapp + mysql database on azure and i've set ftp username/pass. I'm following this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/

Everything is fine up to the ftp part, i just can't connect to that ftp. I tried using the username/pass i set in Deployment Credentials. I tried using the username/pass i see in the PublishSettings file, but nothing is working.

I tried via linux ftp cmd and filezila and played with active/passive.
When i telnet ip 21 i'm getting timeout too.

Could someone please explain how to connect to that azure ftp?

Thanks

Comment: Please see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273360/connecting-to-azure-website-via-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the offical documents, [the section `Deploy by copying files to Azure manually` of the doc `Deploy your app to Azure App Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp) introduce the steps of deploying the WebApp via FTP.

The key point of deploying via FTP on Azure is the FTP connection information, you can follow the steps 5 to 7 of [the section `Get MySQL and FTP connection information` of the doc `Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using FTP`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/#get-mysql-and-ftp-connection-information) to find them from the `.publishsettings` file got on the Azure new portal, please see the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One common problem is that you need to have the username look like `YourSiteName\YourUserName` and not just `YourUserName`.

If you look under 'FTP/Deployment username' in the Azure portal, it gives the correct name with the site name prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The method shown in the tutorial you link to is how I do it when I need to lookup my azure credentials - by downloading the Publish Profile and pulling the information out of there.

Here's how I do it:
using FileZilla (https://filezilla-project.org/) I plug the publishurl in the host field, leave the port blank, select FTP - File Transfer Protocol, use explicit FTP over TLS if available, Logon Type: Normal, enter userName in the user field, userPWD in the password field.

Click Connect and the FTP connection is made (after I click the security msg).

So it's a plain old FTP connection. There's nothing special going on.

If this isn't working for you I would suggest the problem isn't with your credentials, check the webapp has been started in azure, check you can ftp with another site\server.

Good luck. Hope this helps.