# How to deploy an ASP.NET project to Azure with WebDeploy

Tags: asp.net, azure, webdeploy

A little background (before I get downvoted to oblivion!)

I'm working on an intranet-hosted ASP.NET web application in a highly secure environment. At the moment it's deployed by building a package in Visual Studio, the zip file is copied onto the server and installed in IIS using WebDeploy (right-click -> Deploy -> Import Application).

What I'd like to do is deploy a sanitised version of this application to an Azure Web Site for demonstration purposes, however most of the standard Azure deployment methods do not apply to me because:

- I work on a secure network so Visual Studio is blocked from connecting to Azure (rendering 95% of documentation irrelevant!)
- installable software is strictly controlled on this network so I cannot install the Azure SDK needed to create Service Definitions, Configurations and Packages
- The only machine I have access to which *can* connect to Azure is woefully underpowered and can only run puTTY, PowerShell and basic text editors.

At the moment, I have a Windows VM in Azure just running IIS and WebDeploy - this works but seems like overkill (and a good way to burn through my credit) when Web Apps in theory do everything I need.

What can I do?

Comment: How about good old FTP deployment? Will that work for you? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

Comment: Also please see this thread if FTP is a viable option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273360/connecting-to-azure-website-via-ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option may be to checkin the WebDeploy package to a free subscription of Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS = TFS in the cloud) and then create a deployment pipeline in VSTS using the new Release Management features.

https://www.visualstudio.com/features/release-management-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

in that case:

1) FTP from your machine using your own FTP client or i would recommend to use [PSFTP from Putty package.](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

2) Still WebDeploy, but use that to generate the needed files, then you can use [PowerShell like that](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/deploying-an-azure-website-using-powershell/).

Comment: Doesn't 2) still require a WebDeploy build targeted at Azure to generate Publish-WebApplicationWebsite.ps1 and AzureWebSitePublishModule.psm1? Or is everything I need in the Azure PowerShell module?

Comment: Yes, it will require that. Sorry, that approach will need Azure SDK installed, i completely forgot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use https://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ to connect to azure websites. It works with HTTP, only problem could be a corporate proxy.