# How do I give only dlls and static files to a customer to deploy to Azure

Tags: .net, azure, deployment

I have created a .net web API project and I wish to give the dlls to some customers so that they can deploy it to azure as a web app.

While azure seem to expect the solution and build it there. Is there a way around?

**[Update]**

We can deploy ASP.Net applications hosted on GitHub repositories directly to Azure as an App Service. Azure App service automatically detects the project type and deploy a web app in isolated VM (shared/dedicated). So we can publish a GitHub Repository with dlls and config files and share it with customers. This also have added advantage of easily pushing updates to such customers. Here's link to a [write up](http://blog.minhazav.xyz/2017/03/13/easy-way-to-allow-customers-to-deploy-web-apps-to-azure-without-going-through-azure-marketplace/).

Answer (score 1):

Your customers could connect to the Web App with FTP using the publishing credentials and put the files there.

This answer shows how that is done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25278829/1658906

Another option is using something like OneDrive or Dropbox for Continuous Deployment in the Web App. This allows you to synchronize a folder in e.g. OneDrive to a Web App.

Though I am not sure why they cannot give you RBAC access in the new portal so you could do the deployment.

Comment: That's one possible solution but I'm looking for some way to deploy without much steps like deploying from Github. I guess syncing from Onedrive is one solution

Comment: Using OneDrive with continuous deployment is certainly another nice option :)