# Download web app from azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, download

Ok.

I have deleted my ASP.NET project on accident, however, I have it already deployed on MS Azure. I can see all the files in my Server Explorer and the website works perfectly. However I would like to continue working on it.

Is there any possibility to recover / completely download my web app?

[image]

If anyone could tell me how to download my website and maybe link me an example, thank you.

Comment: You accidentally deleted it from source control as well? Anyway, only the compiled binaries will be there probably. So no source code unless you try to decompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up FTP access to your Azure application ([Connecting to Azure website via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273360/connecting-to-azure-website-via-ftp)) and then download from there. The code behind will all be compiled though so you'll have to use something to decompile that (.NET Reflector will do the trick).

Comment: Yeah it worked out. Only thing I did differently: used dotpeek to decompile

Comment: Now you've dodged that bullet consider signing up for some source control if you are not already using it. GitHub (https://github.com/) or the hosted TFS (https://visualstudio.com) - pretty sure there are free options.