# Azure FTP login via command line / batch file fails

Tags: windows, azure, cmd, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to connect by FTP to an Azure Web App. I downloaded the publish profile and copied the login to my FTP client and can connect successfully. But when i use `ftp.exe` from Windows then i am not able to connect to the same host with the same credentials.

I have read [Connecting to Azure website via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273360/connecting-to-azure-website-via-ftp) but those solutions do not fix my problem.

This is the output:

```
C:\Projects>ftp
ftp> open waws-prod-am2-201.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
Connected to waws-prod-am2-201.drip.azurewebsites.windows.net.
220 Microsoft FTP
Service 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
User (waws-prod-am2-201.drip.azurewebsites.windows.net:(none)): firstserver\$firstserver
331 Password required    
Password: 
530 User cannot log in.
Login failed.
Invalid command.
```

Also tried with username `firstserver` from the Windows command prompt, no difference. Do not forget: when logging in via commercial FTP client software I CAN login successfully.

I tried backslashing the backslash and/or the dollar sign, but nothing helps. What is going wrong, how do i login from the command prompt using the Windows default `ftp.exe`?

[image: FTP client logging into Azure Web App]

[image: Windows FTP.exe failing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `ftp` in debug mode (`-d` switch), you will see that it truncates the password to 32 characters. That's why the connection fails.

Try using a shorter password. Otherwise you will have to use another command-line FTP client.